# How to delete specific rows in excel by xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

Suppose there is a test.xlsx like :

| No.1 | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 13-Feb-04 |
| 2 | 20-Feb-04 |
| 3 | 20-Mar-08 |

I want to delete some rows which date is early than 13-Feb-04.Because it has many rows, so the following code snippet finds the last date that happened prior to the 13-Feb-04.

```
import datetime

for day in ws.range('B2:L{}'.format(last_row)):
# checks if day is not prior to the key date
    if day.value <= datetime.datetime(2004, 2, 13, 0, 0):
        # since day is past the modification date,
        # the row we want is the previous one, hence minus 1
        to_delete = int(day.get_address(0, 0)[1:])-1
        # leave the for cycle
        break
```

the last_row is obtained by

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book('test.xlsx')
ws = wb.sheets["Sheet1"]
last_row = ws.range(1,1).end('down').row
```

But the `to_delete` only gets the value 1 in it.I check the xlwings doc ,but I cannot find some tips for the problem.Can someboday give me some suggestions?thx..

Answer (score 2):

after several hours of trial and error, this seems to work:

```
import datetime

for day in ws.range('L2:L{}'.format(last_row)):   

    if day.value <= datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 24, 0, 0):
    
        delete_date_row = int(day.get_address(0, 0)[1:])-1  

 ws.range('2:{}'.format(delete_date_row)).api.Delete()

# note: remove the break statement
```